# Neo4j - still duplicate relationships with 'create unique'

Tags: neo4j, unique, relationship

I am currently trying to create relationships between Person nodes and Item nodes.
But relationships with given properties and values between the two should be unique.
So according to the Neo4j documentation, using `CREATE UNIQUE` should be enough:

```
MATCH (p:Person), (i) 
WHERE id(p) = 561 
AND id(i) = 213 
Create Unique (p)-[:TAG {comment:'test comment',date:timestamp()}]->(i);
```

But when running this query multiple times, I get as many duplicate relationships.
Does anyone know how to correct this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to ensure that the created relation will be unique, use MERGE instead, CREATE UNIQUE will only consider two relationships equal if every one of their properties are the same.

Comment: I've tested the following query: 
MATCH (p:Person), (i) 
WHERE id(p) = 561 
AND id(i) = 213 
Merge (p)-[:TAG {comment:'test comment',date:timestamp()}]->(i);

which still creates new relationships as long as the date property is different for each call.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found out the date value would be different between each create unique call, which makes each relationship unique.
So I guess I'll have to remove the date property to enforce the uniqueness on the remaining properties.